# Dynamically loading modules at runtime in Python 3

Tags: python

Which is the recommended way to lazy load files in Python 3?

I've built this function by copy-past from Python 2 code

```
def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        ns = {}
        fn = os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'cmd_{}.py'.format(cmd_name))

        with open(fn) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), str(fn), 'exec')
            eval(code, ns, ns)

        return ns['cli']
```

but I'm not sure if it is the right way. It uses `compile` and `eval`

**EDIT**

After using `import` like this:

```
def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
    cmd_mod = import_module('{}.cmd_{}'.format(cmd_folder, cmd_name))
```

this is the result:

```
  File "aws_iam_cli/cli.py", line 23, in get_command
    cmd_mod = import_module('{}.cmd_{}'.format(cmd_folder, cmd_name))
  File "/Users/salvatoremazzarino/awsiam/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/Users/salvatoremazzarino/awsiam/aws_iam_cli/commands'
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        mod = import_module('aws_iam_cli.commands.cmd_{}'
                            .format(cmd_name))
        return mod.cli
```

and the error:

```
  File "/Users/salvatoremazzarino/awsiam/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_iam_cli'
```

This is the dir tree:

```
├── aws_iam_cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── commands
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── cmd_dump.py
│   └── provider
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── policy.py
│       └── role.py
```

Inside commands I have a module and I call inside that module:

```
from aws_iam_cli.provider.role import fetch_roles
```

Comment: Almost certainly not, but you haven't really described your problem. What do you mean by "lazy loading" here? How would you use this and why don't you want to just use the standard `import`?

Comment: I have to read, compile and exec files at runtime rather than importing statically them. Do something described here http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/#custom-multi-commands

Comment: @DanielRoseman so what would you recommend?

Comment: What do you want to do with that? The answer varies for "I want endusers to upload python scripts" and "I want library users to easily extend my library".

Answer (score 4):

You can use importlib.import_module to load modules dynamically at run time. So for example:

```
from importlib import import_module

# load module
pckg_name = 'commands'  # I assume all your commands are in this pckg
cmd_mod = import_module('{}.cmd_{}'.format(pckg_name, cmd_name))

# run command (I'm assuming the module contains a function with the 'cmd_name')
cmd_mod.cmd_name()
```

I think this kind of approach will be cleaner and safer and should work with what you are doing.

Comment: Do you have an \__init__.py in your package (cmd_folder)?

Comment: yep. I have it.

Comment: Ah - your cmd_folder is the full path. We want just the <pckg_name>.<module name> e.g. commands.a_command

Comment: Unfortunately still having issues. I'm going to update the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157795/discussion-between-mazzy-and-sam-redway).